# authentication dialog not appear using Tortoise

Tags: authentication, tortoisesvn

I create local repository and in svnserve.conf file uncomment some line to get this:

> [general]
>    anon-access = none
>    auth-access = write
>    password-db = passwd
>   [sasl]
>    use-sasl = false

and in passwd

> [users]
>   user= userpass

But when I do Checkout or other operation, authentication dialog don't appear :/
 Can someone know why ?? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe your credentials are cached and TortoiseSVN use them instead of asking, see [Client Credentials Caching](http://ubc.fay.ar.us/pub/subversion/Book/ch06s02.html#svn-ch-6-sect-2.2).

Comment: I look there but too many options :/ How to enable check pass and user in conf folder od my repo?

Comment: Is this your first repo? I highly recommend that you read SVN Book, here: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/